# Pyroot: Import Error: no module named handlers

Tags: jupyter, python-3.5, root-framework, pyroot

I have been trying to build ROOT from source on my archlinux machine. I had gcc 5.3 which was not compatible with Cling so I downgraded to 4.9.3. Now the root build is successful but when I try to run a notebook in root I get the

`Import Error: No module named handlers`

I am using python3.5 with jupyter notebook. I tried building pyroot and then again installing root but it didn't work either. The handlers.py file does exist where it is supposed to be, the only problem is that it is not getting imported.

Comment: How have you installed Python (e.g. pyenv, system, virtualenv, etc.)? How do you try and run the notebook?

Comment: Same problem here. Stuck at this and can't find a solution.